# how to sync phone contacts into gmail in android programmatically using google contacts api 

Tags: android, google-api, synchronization, android-contacts

How to synchronize Android native contacts into Google account using Google API.
Provide some useful links.

Comment: http://immigrationroad.com/blog/how-to-sync-android-phone-contacts-with-google-gmail/

Comment: i need to sync programmatically

Comment: Nirav plz send the code..i need to implement

Comment: i need a code.i dont have a idea

Comment: http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/1/

Comment: thnk u. See ur tutorial is used to working with native app. Not to syn.

Comment: no nirav ranpara i didn't get

Comment: You are having a misconception about SO and bounty : this is not like I have one application to do, you do my work I will offer you points through bounty. Please read FAQ.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syncing happens automatically. You can add or delete contacts programatically. But the syncing is handled by the OS automatically if and only if the user has enabled 'sync conatcts' option in phone settings.

You can, however run a sync routine that can call the syncing process if syncing is enabled by the user using something like this:

```
private void requestSync()
{
    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account[] accounts = am.getAccounts();

    for (Account account : accounts)
    {
        int isSyncable = ContentResolver.getIsSyncable(account, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY);

        if (isSyncable > 0)
        {
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
            ContentResolver.requestSync(accounts[0], ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, extras);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You also need to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />` to the manifest

Answer (score 0):

The following could also be a good answer. Its similar to the above one, but default Settings app uses code something like this:

```
private void requestSyncForAccounts() {
    SyncAdapterType[] syncAdapters = ContentResolver.getSyncAdapterTypes();
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(PeopleActivity.this).getAccounts();
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        for (int j = 0; j < syncAdapters.length; j++) {
            SyncAdapterType sa = syncAdapters[j];
            if (ContentResolver.getSyncAutomatically(account, sa.authority)) {
                ContentResolver.requestSync(account, sa.authority, extras);
            }
        }
    }
}
```